# Alternative to running multiple commands to configure application

Tags: docker, build, devops, build-tools

When I develop my applications I have lots of things going on. They're usually micro services and each has their own build tools. For example I have to run a build script for `hugo`, and a build script for `webpack`, and some `gulp` tasks. I'll also have to generate some files, keys etc.

It's a huge pain to have to run these manually. When I test in dev, and staging I'm constantly rebuilding the docker containers running the same commands. It gets painful.

Are there any tools that can help with this? Where I can run one command and have it rebuild everything in my application? A bash script would work but that's not an option.

I've seen people use build scripts like in C, but I can't find anything similar for devops. Maybe docker has a tool for this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would a bash script not work? Check the docker `command` argument [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command). You can tell docker to run commands when you're creating your services, which would allow you to run bash scripts automatically everytime you re-deploy instead of doing it manually.

Comment: Most applications that I've seen that use that set of tooling use [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) and run something like `npm build` to run all of these tasks.  Make or shell scripts work fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to build your containers rather than use an image.

I'll assume you're using `docker-compose` or `docker stack deploy` to start you containers. In both scenarios, you have a `.yaml` file that describes your services. Let's assume that the following is part of your config right now, to deploy a service in which you'll want to run a build script for webpack, and that you're using a Node.js image as your base (and you can adapt that to your actual scenario easily):

```
# ...
services:
  webpack:
    image: node:8.12.0
    # ...
  # ...
```

Instead of using the image directly, you can specify a build context:

```
# ...
services:
  webpack:
    build:
      context: ./docker/webpack
    # ...
      # ...
  # ...
```

Create a directory structure accordingly so that there's a `docker/webpack` folder. Inside that folder, create a `build-script.sh` shell script with the commands you want to run, and create a [`Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) file. This file should look like:

```
FROM node:8.12.0

COPY build-script.sh /tmp/build-script.sh 

RUN npm install --save-dev webpack \
 && /bin/sh /tmp/build-script.sh
```

Then when you run `docker-compose up` or `docker stack deploy ...`, it will build a container already initialized with the content of the `build-script.sh` script. Obviously there is much more you can do with this `Dockerfile`, but for your use-case, you can start with something pretty simple. You can even avoid creating the script altogether and run all of your commands in a single huge `RUN` statement (using `\` at the end of each line except the last one, and separating different commands with `&&`).

---

Later on, you could even build an image yourself by uploading this `Dockerfile` to github, and making an account on [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/) and linking it to your github. You could call it something like `BugHunterUK-dev-environment` or something and use `image: BugHunterUK-dev-environment:latest` in your Yaml file.